# How to calculate convolution for 2nd conv Layer in CNN, Do we need to average across all feature maps?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

I understand that for the first layer (assuming we have a grayscale image) we calculate the convolution of 3*3 receptive field as a weighted sum of receptive weights with pixels

$ x1 · w1 + x2 · w2 + x3·w3 + ... + xn · wn$

But for the second layer, where we already have $N$ feature maps in the last convolution layer, how would we calculate the convolution(for a particular pixel/cell)? should we take an average of the $N$ weighted sums we have from feature maps?

If the question isn't clear, I have tried to highlighted it from the image taken from [famous 3d visualization.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaharley/vis/conv/)

[image: 2nd layer conv]

In the image, for the pixel in question(hovered and squared) we have inputs coming from 4 feature maps. I think they are four integers (weighted sums of the receptive field of the bottom right corner from each feature map).

How is the value (convolution)  for this particular pixel/cell calculated? showed we take average like below?

(I can add more details if the question is not clear)

```
weighted_sum_fmap1 + weighted_sum_fmap1 + weighted_sum_fmap1 + weighted_sum_fmap1 / 4
```

Comment: Are you referring to **Average Pooling**? See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/pooling-layers-for-convolutional-neural-networks/) blog on Pooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't average across all feature maps.

When the input has multiple channels, **you need your convolution filter to have the same number of channels**. Therefore, the filter "covers" the full depth of the input. Then, you simply perform the element-wise multiplication of the filter with the overlapping region in the input and add all the resulting elements together.

Therefore, if the input to a convolutional layer is a grayscale image, a filter is of dimensions `[3,3,1]`, while if the input is a color image (with 3 channels), your filter is `[3, 3, 3]`, like this ([source](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/guide-convolutional-neural-network-cnn/)):

[image]

The same happens with feature maps with N channels: we need a filter with N channels.